# Pentaho report designer 5.2: export html shows table as whitespace

Tags: pentaho, report-designer

I'm trying to print a mailletter. Which contains a table in html.
The issue is, the table isn't printed when exporting to PDF/HTML.

The field `body_html`comes from a ktr file. ( This file contains some text and a table )

I placed the field in the detail area of the report. On the field-Attributes, I choose `rich-text-type = text/html`.

The expected output should be:

**TEXT HERE

TABLE HERE

TEXT HERE**

When I click PDF preview it shows, me:

**TEXT HERE

WHITESPACE HERE ( for 66 pages )

TEXT HERE**

When I export it as html, I just have a huge gab ( the 66 pages of whitespace ) in my browser ( Chrome or FF ). When I export it as plain text, it just shows me the HTML and not my table (ofcourse).

**TEXT HERE

WHITESPACE HERE (no sign of any table)

TEXT HERE**

When I copy-paste the HTML in a Notepad++ and run it from there, it works perfectly and I get my table.

I also tagged under the following path *File > Configuration > output-table-html* these settings on:

- BodyFragment = true
- ExternalStyle = true
- ForceBufferedWriting = true
- TableRowBorderDefinition = true
- UseTableLayoutFixed = true

### **Q:** Is there anything I'm overlooking or why isn't it printing my table?

**EDIT**: 
When I just open the HTML it's not that big. When I export it in pentaho 1 column takes a whole page of +- 3000 px wide. So I get multiple pages I found out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the column width from the Pentaho report designer.
If the width of the columns exceed the width of page in report designer, it will not be able to show the contents.
Make sure the combined width of all the columns must be equal to or less than the page width.

Comment: When I just open the HTML it's not that big. When I export it in pentaho 1 column takes a whole page of +- 3000 px wide. So I get multiple pages I found out. Any suggestions?